# Confusion with the use of react-router package

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and was learning how to properly use React Router with React all together. As you know, the React Router was divided into three packages: react-router, react-router-dom and react-router-native. So, both react-router-dom and react-router-native by default have react-router inside of them. The question is since both react-router-dom and react-router-native include react-router then what is the reason to have react-router as separate package?

Comment: you can check this in which you can find all the differences https://stackoverflow.com/a/58580345/6544460

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router):

> This package [react-router] provides the core routing functionality for React Router, but you might not want to install it directly. If you are writing an application that will run in the browser, you should instead install react-router-dom. Similarly, if you are writing a React Native application, you should instead install react-router-native. Both of those will install react-router as a dependency.

So extracting the core functionality into a standalone package can be useful for experimenting, developing, or testing improvements or features that can then be used in the specific packages.

Answer (score 0):

`react-router-dom` is rewritten from `react-router` it means `react-router` is older version.
so for react router follow latest one `react-router-dom`

for your reference you can check this which has all the differences.

[React routing versions](https://www.techiediaries.com/react-router-dom-v4/)